# Blank Remote Desktop 13.04

Tags: 13.04, windows, remote, xrdp

I am having an issue regarding remote desktop from a Windows 7 machine. Right now, the machine with Ubuntu 13.04 has a cracked LCD and is a paperweight until I can replace it. My KVM switch is already using all the ports for two other machines.

The issue begins after I install xrdp. I can remote just fine to the machine, however, when I connect it shows the default Ubuntu desktop background with no interface except the mouse. I cannot right click or anything. Is there a setting I need to enable on the host machine or do I have to configure a user account specifically for remote desktop?

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at this post (http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=4160) which explains in details how to install the xrdp sofware and have it working

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! While this may theoretically answer the question, please summarise the main points to your answer, as the link may stop working in the future.