# how to install xrdp on ubuntu 14.04 (trusty)?

Tags: 14.04, xrdp

I have tried to install xrdp on Ubuntu using `apt-get install xrdp`, but have run into issues similar to other users such as listed in these posts:

- [ubuntu 14.04 xrdp grey](https://askubuntu.com/questions/449785/ubuntu-14-04-xrdp-grey)
- [No login box for xrdp](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425687/no-login-box-for-xrdp)
- [Blank Remote Desktop 13.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/309476/blank-remote-desktop-13-04)
- [How do I set up xrdp session that reuses an existing session?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133343/how-do-i-set-up-xrdp-session-that-reuses-an-existing-session)
- [Copy and Pasting issues with XRDP](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2043102)

How can I install xrdp easily and robustly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the [scareygliders script](http://scarygliders.net/x11rdp-o-matic-information/) to install XRDP as it is more stable than the default ubuntu xrdp package and also gives you copy and paste functionality between the host and client.

However, I had issues setting up XRDP with lubuntu and standard ubuntu desktops so I eventually went with xubuntu desktop:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
# I'm not sure if xvfb is required, but have installed it just to be sure
sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop xfce4 xvfb 

git clone https://github.com/scarygliders/X11RDP-o-Matic.git
cd X11RDP-o-Matic
sudo ./X11rdp-o-matic.sh --justdoit
echo xfce4-session >~/.xsession
# if screensaver hogs the cpu
echo 'mode: off' > ~/.xscreensaver
```

Comment: just a warning to everyone: `X11rdp-o-matic.sh --justdoit` takes about 20 minutes to run

Comment: It does take a while to build. I raised a request to be able to download pre-built binary packages. See https://github.com/scarygliders/X11RDP-o-Matic/issues/39 for more info. Feel free to add your +1 to the issue ;)

Comment: the x11rdpomatic config script puts `startxfce4` into the .xsession  file, are you sure that `xfce4-session` is better? I can't get either to work with Ubuntu 14.04 though.

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, what is happening? Do you just get a black screen?

Comment: I got a message that said "login failed, giving up" etc. I'm having better luck with TightVNC and https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-vnc-for-ubuntu-12

Comment: This is the [script](https://github.com/snowch/stratos-vagrant-box/blob/master/stratos/stratos.sh#L375) I use on a vagrant ubuntu 14.04 box.

Comment: The linked script is on a private git server and inaccessible.

Answer (score 2):

To have xrdp working with ubuntu 14.04, you need to specify an alternate desktop.  In order to have a working xrdp install, perform the following actions

1. install xrdp (**sudo apt-get install xrdp**)
2. install alternate desktop (in this example, let's say you want to
   install xfce),so you would type in a terminal**sudo apt-get install xfce4**
3. Finally, you have to tell xrdp that you want to use xfce, so from a terminal session, you type the following command echo xfce4-session >~/.xsession
4. Try to connect and you should be good to go

You can find detailed instruction via this [link](http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=5305). If you do not like xfce; you can install other desktop alternative such as LXDE,Mate-desktop,kde....

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way - coming from many different sources and try and error - but now it even works through Microsoft RD client on my iOS iPad 2 - fun!

Windows:
I did install Windows 10 Pro Hyper V
I did install virtual machine first generation - Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Ubuntu:
I did install xubuntu-desktop (for xfce4 which works - I do not care for my taste if I like or not - it works!)
I did install xrde
I did create a remote user
I did grant sudo group to it
I did create with sudo rights via vi a .xsession file (like others) in the home directory of the created remote user
I made the .xsession file being able to execute via chmod in the home directory of that created remote user
But - and that I only found once - I did start my .xsession file first with:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

I did not use echo ...

I entered via vi line two:

```
xfce4-session
```

After that I did a restart of the virtual Ubuntu machine

And after the restart I was able to go to the IP of the virtual Ubuntu with the remote user created ending in a running graphical xfce4 session in the out of the box Microsoft Remote Desktop Connection without that grey screen.

I was so lucky and proud with all tha reading which I tried myself not getting a satisfying result like others with blank/grey screens and doing a combination like that from different sources myself running it as RDP session from Windows 10 or - as already written - through my iPad 2 that I like to share my experiences here with others helping me getting to this point - thanks to all!

Comment: xrde is typo - xrdp is correct