# xdrp on Ubuntu 16

Tags: xrdp

I am very new to Linux and installed Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial with the Cinnamon desktop environment.

How do I enable enable xrdp on this server installation?

Thanks

Comment: Did you check this? http://askubuntu.com/questions/498873/how-to-install-xrdp-on-ubuntu-14-04-trusty?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Ubuntu 16.04, you can try the following
Step 1 - install TigerVNC
Step 2 - Install the xrdp package (sudo apt-get install xrdp)
Step 3 - you are done

Detailed instructions can be found [here](http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=10241)

If you want to be more adventurous, you can try to compile the xrdp 0.9 as well, you can find also detailed instructions [here](http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=10273)

Hope this help
See ya